# Multilabel text classification/clustering in python with tf-idf

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, document, text-classification, tf-idf

I have five plain text documents in a directory that are already clustered based on their content and named as such cluster1.txt, cluster2.txt and so on,  so they are functioning as my corpus. Otherwise they don't have any labels, they are just named as such. 
My task is to cluster a new text document with new sentences, but not the whole document as a whole, instead I should cluster each sentence into one of these 5 cluster or classes and also do a confusion matrix with the recall and precision score to show how similar the sentences are to the clusters.

I first tried to do it with a kNN and then a kmeans, but I think my logic is flawed since this is not a clustering problem, it's a classification problem, right?
Well at least I tried to preprocess the text (removing stop words, lemmatize, lowercasing, tokenizing) and then I calculated the termfrequency with a countvectorizer and then the tf-idf
I kinda have problems with the logic with this problem.

Anyway, this is what I tried so far, but now I'm kinda stuck, any help is appreciated

```
import glob
import os
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'C:/Users/ds191033/FH/Praktikum/Testdaten/Clusters', "*.txt"))
   corpus = []
for file_path in file_list:
with open(file_path, encoding="utf8") as f_input:
corpus.append(f_input.read())

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('german')

wpt = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('german')
lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

def normalize_document(doc):
    # lower case and remove special characters\whitespaces
    doc = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', doc, re.I|re.A)
    doc = doc.lower()
    tokens = wpt.tokenize(doc)
    # filter stopwords out of document
    filtered_tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stop_words]
    #lemmatize
    for w in filtered_tokens:
        lemmatized_tokens = [lem.lemmatize(t) for t in filtered_tokens]
    # re-create document from filtered tokens
    doc = ' '.join(lemmatized_tokens)
    return doc

normalize_corpus = np.vectorize(normalize_document)

norm_corpus = normalize_corpus(corpus)
norm_corpus

cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1.)
cv_matrix = cv.fit_transform(norm_corpus)
cv_matrix = cv_matrix.toarray()
cv_matrix

# get all unique words in the corpus
vocab = cv.get_feature_names()
# show document feature vectors
pd.DataFrame(cv_matrix, columns=vocab)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1., use_idf=True)
tv_matrix = tv.fit_transform(norm_corpus)
tv_matrix = tv_matrix.toarray()

vocab = tv.get_feature_names()
pd.DataFrame(np.round(tv_matrix, 2), columns=vocab)
```